# How to pool a connection in google apps script?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, connection-pooling

Previously in scripting in **Google Apps Script**, I opened and closed my Jdbc connection in all the functions.

In order to speed up my application, it seems to be better to leave the connection open and use it in another function. However, I don't know how I should do that in **Google Apps Script**.

Can anyone give me a suggestion or an example?

Comment: Thank you! This will help me so much.

Comment: Sorry, you need to retain it at ScriptDB. CacheService only retain String values.

Comment: I built the solution bellow.

Comment: 1) The scriptDB is deprecated 2) the JDBC connection is automatically closed after every execution of the script, so, there is no point to store it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to retain your connection at ScriptDB.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var conn = ScriptDb.getMyDb().query({name : "my_connection"} );
  var connection = null;
  var itemId = null;

  if(conn.getSize() == 0) {
    Logger.log(" Connection not found, creating new one");
    connection = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<instance>', 'user', 'password');
    itemId = ScriptDb.getMyDb().save({name : "my_connection", connection : connection}).getId();

  }else {
    Logger.log(" Connection found, retrieving "+conn.getSize());
    var dbItem  = conn.next();
    connection = dbItem.connection;
    itemId = dbItem.getId();
  }

  //Check if it is closed
  if(connection.isClosed()) {
    connection = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<instance>', 'user', 'password');

    //After opening remember to save to dabatase again and retain only one connection
    ScriptDb.getMyDb().removeById(itemId);
    ScriptDb.getMyDb().save({name : "my_connection", connection : connection});
  }

  //Use your connection here

  //Remenber to close it based in some criteria
}
```

Example [here](https://script.google.com/d/1zVYUAuNiEFGEV37aeILcE08veFNlruC_qRI3EvGIYWSnl81blb9hhRE0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this helps me much further. I still have one question yet: is retaining it at ScriptDB inevitable?

Comment: I guess that is the only way. Google says that the time to test if a connection is alive is similar to open a new connection so they recomend to always open a new connection but, as you discover, is not really that way. If this answer helped you please thumbs up! :)

Comment: Hi,
Today I worked on the pooling matters. Actually, it is a really nice and creative way of connection pooling. The problem is, however, that scriptDb cannot save a Jdbc-connection. It says: value is not a number, string, boolean etc. Is this an inevitable problem, or do you have some suggestions for this?

I found that in the prepareStatement method, there is a 'setPooled(boolean)' method. Isn't this a possible solution, somehow? Actually, I'm a little stuck on this.

Comment: Use Utilities.jsonStringify(obj) to convert from object to string and use Utilities.jsonParse(jsonString) to convert from string to object.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=pt-br