# How to pool a connection in google apps script without ScriptDB?

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, connection-pooling

I am looking to pool a connection in a similar way [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323522/how-to-pool-a-connection-in-google-apps-script). However I do not wish to use `ScriptDB` which was [deprecated in May 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/script-db).

How would this be achieved without the `ScriptDB` class? Not use connection pooling in Google Apps Script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pool a connection in google apps script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323522/how-to-pool-a-connection-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Reprase better your question or it will be closed. The linked question explains exsctly how to do it. You just want to save ot elsewhere so read the docs on saving data,and post a relevant question with code.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, specially since the linked question/answer does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer in the linked question does not work as you cannot store jdbc connection objects on `ScriptDb`, or anywhere else for that matter. It is not possible to do a connection pool or cache in Apps Script. Even if you ´stringify´ it, when you parse back it'll not work.

One **always** have to create a new connection for every instance/execution of the script.